# Вывод друзей пользователя

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Есть таблица **friends**

В ней поля `friend_id`*(A_I)* | `friend_user_id1` | `friend_user_id2` | `friend_status`

[Пример.jpg](https://pp.vk.me/c424623/v424623371/373/z3akQgpPnxM.jpg)

Как при помощи php вывести значение строк `friend_user_id2`, если `friend_user_id1` равен единице.

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$res = mysql_query('select `friend_user_id2` from `friends` where `friend_user_id1`=1');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
  print('friend '.$row['friend_user_id2'].' <br />');
}
```

не?

Соответственно, если надо вывести всех, кто с такими айдишниками, то

```
$res = mysql_query('select `fr2`.* from `friends` as `fr1` left join `friends` as `fr2` on `fr1`.`friend_user_id2`=`fr2`.`id`  where `fr1`.`friend_user_id1`=1');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
  print('friend '.$row['id'].' - '.$row['friend_user_id1'].' - '.$row['friend_user_id2'].' - '.$row['friends_status'].' <br />');
}
```

Если сюда же приплести таблицу юзеров, получится следующее:

```
$res = mysql_query('select `users`.* from `friends` as `fr1` left join `friends` as `fr2` on `fr1`.`friend_user_id2`=`fr2`.`id` left join `users` as `u` on `fr2`.`id`=`users`.`id`  where `fr1`.`friend_user_id1`=1');
```

Comment: Хорошо. Я успешно получил id пользователей, которые в друзьях. Теперь мне нужно получить информацию о них:
`$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '.$row['friend_user_id2'].'');
 while ( $friends_info = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
  echo 'info '.$friends_info['last_name'].'<br>';
 }`

Но когда я пытаюсь вывести фамилию -- получаю информацию только о первом друге.

Как выводить информацию о всех?

Comment: Обновил.
Везде используется одна и та же конструкция

Select table1nickname.field1name, table2nickname.field1name, ...  
from table1 AS table1nickname   
LEFT JOIN //right join, inner join  
table2 AS table2nickname  
ON  
table1.fieldXXX = table2.fieldYYY

Comment: дело не в том что в силе. а в том, что вы своим ответом подталкиваете человека на неправильный путь. устарело оно довольно давно, просто не в статусе depricated.

Comment: @eicto, ну напишите правильный. Я бы тоже поучился, кстати. Особенно, решение на PDO интересно.

Comment: примеры на php.net, зачем ихх писать еще раз

Comment: Ну, тем не менее вы не поленились скопировать выдержку из документации, информационная ценность которой в данном вопросе существенно ниже.

Comment: у меня темплейт в закладках

Comment: @eicto: всё же, у вас есть знания о том, какие примеры из php.net являются релевантными. Если вы их даже просто скопируете в отдельный ответ (не говоря уже о там, чтобы подогнать под вопрос), и ТС, и остальные участники сайта, возможно, чему-то научатся. Если вы ещё и аргументируете, почему лучше так, а не иначе, вы улучшите Вселенную вокруг себя и левелапнете планету.

Comment: если будет желание/время нарисую исследование (если смогу что нить оригинальное добавить) а под каждый вопрос делать примеры простых вещей не очень то нужно, в данном случае релевантные примеры в доке. смысл моих копипаст доки вот в чем - **не делайте и не советуйте никому делать новый код на основе расширения mysql - это вредит вашей карме**

Comment: @knes Эмм.. А откуда берутся fr1 и fr2?

Comment: из воздуха.   
    
    `friends` as `fr2`

Вот тут мы говорим, что ЭТА friends теперь будет называться fr2. Тот самый никнейм. Кстати, слово as можо опустить, но я оставил, чтобы было понятнее.

Вы можете вместо fr2 использовать любое слово, хоть vasya_pupkin, главное, не забудте его везде по запросу заменить.